# groovy how create array with name?

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

IM trying to use this command in groovy but I cant print the array

appears and error

```
       Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at Test.main(Test.groovy:7)

how I could solve this

I use this same command without this line  and this works

```
          testArray["fff"] = "B"
```

this is my code

I dont know because I cant create this 2d array

```
 def testArray =  []
  testArray[0] = "A"
      testArray["fff"] = "B"
      testArray[2] = "C"

   println testArray
```

please give me a help

Comment: Array indices should be integer values, not strings.

Comment: what is `testArray["fff"]` ?

Comment: hi I see that in ruby is possible create array with name but IN groovy i dont know

Comment: use `testArray = [:]` instead.  And this is not an array but a **map**.  I assume that this is also the case in ruby.   AFAIK only PHP has some odd array/map mishmash

Comment: very thankyou cfrick works  ; thanks for all

Comment: If you put this in answer ; i will give best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `testArray = [:]` instead. And this is *not* an array but a **map** (a `LinkedHashMap` to be specific and `[:]` is the literal Groovy uses to create it).  Maps in Java/Groovy are associative data structures to store key-value-relations.  Access via `map[key]` is an enhancement, that Groovy brings to the table.

Comment: @cfrick can please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717505/groovy-create-a-map-with-jax-b-objects-specific-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Arrays only take ints as indices. 
"fff" is not a valid value for an index, therefore java crashes, telling you its a mismatch.

If you want to create a 2d array of Strings then you should try this.

`String[][] testArray = new String[x][y];`

where x and y are the dimensions for this array.